# CSS on Server Side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, less

I ran into [LESS website](http://lesscss.org/) and this is the description of they are doing"

> LESS extends CSS with dynamic behavior such as variables, mixins, operations and functions. LESS runs on both the client-side (IE 6+, Webkit, Firefox) and server-side, with Node.js.

What does it mean "and server-side" with Node.js? I know that you can write server-side code with javascript using Node.js, but what is the meaning of having CSS on server-side and how is it useful?

Comment: I would imagine that on the server is parses the style sheets and applies them with in-line style tags. Though this is only a best-guess.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there was server side CSS hence there is everything in its serverside form nowadays, allowing users to sign up with hexadecimal code witch gets encrypted into binary code of color in grid-based database. And everyone would flex with this technology.

Comment: Honestly, even I came across something known as server-side CSS. I do not recollect which blog it was however I am extremely confused. I mean, "server-side" CSS? What would that mean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> What does it mean "and server-side" with Node.js? I know that you can write server-side code with javascript using Node.js, but what is the meaning of having CSS on server-side and how is it useful?

It's not the **CSS** that's (optionally) done server-side, it's the *LESS processing*, which results in normal CSS that gets sent to the client.

So if you have a `.less` file on your web server with this:

```
@color: #4D926F;

#header {
  color: @color;
}
h2 {
  color: @color;
}
```

...and you have your web server configured to process `.less` files through the LESS compiler running under Node.js (e.g., just as `.php` files are processed through the PHP interpreter, `.py` files through the Python interpreter, etc.), then the *output* of the LESS compiler (pure CSS) gets generated and sent to the client:

```
#header {
  color: #4D926F;
}
h2 {
  color: #4D926F;
}
```

This is (a tiny bit) more load on your server, but means you don't have to worry about running the LESS compiler on the browser (e.g., you can support non-JavaScript clients).

Comment: What do you mean by "It's not the CSS that's (optionally) done server-side" ?

Comment: CSS is applied by the browser, so it's done client-side. What's happening server-side is turning the LESS syntax (which is a marked improvement on CSS) into CSS syntax.

Comment: The way @T.J.Crowder is describing this sounds like the CSS files are getting processed every time a page loads. That's a bit inefficient -- they should really be processed once at deployment.

Comment: @mlissner: That's one of the options with less as well (and the one I would certainly use).

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure it means that you can run the LESS code with Node.js during your application build phase in order to pre-expand the CSS.

In other words, it lets you do that server-side before deployment (or, I guess, on demand, if you wanted to) in order to improve client-side performance.

Answer (score 2):

The LESS compiler is implemented in JavaScript and the compiler can run both on the client as well as the server (using NodeJS)

Answer (score 1):

my bet: it would compile the css server-side, and push it to the client

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly what it says. You place your .less files on the server and the server will take care of the parsing, compiling and minifying.